# responsive design instead of adaptive for this example - possible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so i am trying to make a responsive page. the problem is that why it comes down to mobile the data needs to sit within a list.

I will explain with some example code

so this could be the output on desktop

```html
<aside class="mainLeft">        
    <ul class='tabs'>
        <li><a id="#tab1">option1</a></li>
        <li><a id="#tab2">option2</a></li>
        <li><a id="#tab3">option3</a></li>
    </ul>
</aside>
        
<aside class="mainRight" >
       <div id="tabl">
      <img src="image1.png">
            <h3 >Title 1</h3>
            <p>Text 1</p>
 </div>
    <div id="tab2">
   <img src="image2.png">
         <h3 >Title 2</h3>
         <p>Text 2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3">
      <img src="image3.png">
         <h3 >Title 3</h3>
         <p>Text 3</p>
 </div>  
</aside>
```

so to the left is a tab menu and to the right there is the content and that all good but when I move to mobile i want the content to be under each tab - so something like this

```html
  <aside class="mainLeft">
         <ul class='tabs'>
             <li><a id="#tab1">option1</a>
                 <div id="tabl">
           <img src="image1.png">
                    <h3 >Title 1</h3>
                    <p>Text 1</p>
           </div>
              </li>
              <li><a id="#tab2">option2</a>
                  <div id="tab2">
             <img src="image2.png">
                      <h3 >Title 2</h3>
                      <p>Text 2</p>
            </div>
              </li>
              <li><a id="#tab3">option3</a>
                  <div id="tab3">
             <img src="image3.png">
                      <h3 >Title 3</h3>
                      <p>Text 3</p>
            </div>
              </li>
          </ul>
</aside>
<aside class="mainRight" >
            
</aside>
```

I am trying to think of a way to do this using css or maybe a little JS

what is the best way of doing this.

I have thought of adding a JS detector to see if its a mobile or desktop but again this makes it adaptive and not responsive

i also thought about having the second code and trying to absolute or fixed position the content but this doesn't work

any suggestions welcome :)

Comment: It looks like it will be easier to add to your .mainRight block desktop markup additional headings and hide them with media queries on big screen sizes, but for small screens you show them, but hide your tabs block. But it would be better to make initial markup more universal: get rid of your separate tabs block, and use something like your second markup.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this. Hide the top list when you're on mobile and toggle single `<li>`s on each row.

```
<aside class="mainLeft">        
    <ul class='tabs'>
        <li><a id="#tab1">option1</a></li>
        <li><a id="#tab2">option2</a></li>
        <li><a id="#tab3">option3</a></li>
    </ul>
</aside>

<aside class="mainRight" >
     <div id="tabl">
          <li class="mobile-li">option 1</li>
          <img src="image1.png">
          <h3 >Title 1</h3>
          <p>Text 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2">
         <li class="mobile-li">option 2</li>
         <img src="image2.png">
         <h3 >Title 2</h3>
         <p>Text 2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3">
         <li class="mobile-li">option 3</li>
         <img src="image3.png">
         <h3 >Title 3</h3>
         <p>Text 3</p>
    </div>  
</aside>
```

CSS

```
.mobile-li{
   display:none; /* Hidden by default */
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px)   {
    aside.mainLeft{
      display:none;
   }

   .mobile-li{
      display:block; /* Toggle on mobile */
   }

}
```